Brushed metal texture - can't rotate the texture to get circular on top
I created this brushed metal texture out of Noise Texture. Left in the picture is the actual object I want to put the texture on to, and right is the sphere with the same texture.
The sphere creates this circular pattern out of the texture (probably because of its form), but I want this circular pattern to be on my actual object as well.

I tried to rotate it around using the Mapping node but it doesn't give me the circular pattern, just the streaks in different angle. Is there a way to achieve the circular part to show on top somehow?

